# Count Distinct and extract Values not in Group By

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to get a full table with an additional column with a count distinct grouped by only a set of fields, not the full table.

Basically, I have this table:

```
| mandt | ktopl |    yhkonto | yhhykto | yhbwkz |
|-------|-------|------------|---------|--------|
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |      1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     21 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     82 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     87 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |      1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     21 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     82 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     87 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039630000 |   39630 |      1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039630000 |   39630 |     21 |
```

and I want to get this result, with an additional column, where I get the count of distinct values of `yhhykto` grouping by `mandt`, `ktopl` and `yhkonto`:

```
| mandt | ktopl |    yhkonto | yhhykto | yhbwkz | cnt_yhhykto |
|-------|-------|------------|---------|--------|-------------|
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |      1 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     21 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     82 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0034600000 |     346 |     87 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |      1 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     21 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     82 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039410000 |   39410 |     87 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039630000 |   39630 |      1 |           1 |
|   111 |   SAG | 0039630000 |   39630 |     21 |           1 |
```

I have a working query:

```
select distinct yh010.mandt,
                yh010.ktopl,
                yh010.yhkonto,
                yh010.yhhykto,
                yh010.yhbwkz,
                yh010_x.cnt_yhhykto
    from yh010
    inner join (
        select distinct yh010.mandt,
                        yh010.ktopl,
                        yh010.yhkonto,
                        count(distinct yh010.yhhykto) as cnt_yhhykto
            from yh010
            group by yh010.mandt, yh010.ktopl, yh010.yhkonto
    ) yh010_x
        on  yh010_x.mandt   = yh010.mandt
        and yh010_x.ktopl   = yh010.ktopl
        and yh010_x.yhkonto = yh010.yhkonto
;
```

But this inner join with itself doesn't seem the best solution. Or is it?
I was thinking more like in terms of:

```
select yh010.mandt,
        yh010.ktopl,
        yh010.yhkonto,
        yh010.yhhykto,
        yh010.yhbwkz
        count( distinct yh010.yhhykto 
            ) over ( group by yh010.mandt, yh010.ktopl, yh010.yhkonto 
        ) as cnt_dist
    from yh010
;
```

But `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.`

Should I keep that working query or is there any better option?

The fiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f98f/9)

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately COUNT( Distinct fieldname ) OVER (Partition BY clause is not supported on HANA database

Answer (score 2):

Based on this description:

> I want to get this result, getting the count of distinct values of
>   yhhykto grouping by mandt, ktopl and yhkonto

You want this query:

```
select y.mandt, y.ktopl, y.yhkonto,
       count(distinct y.yhhykto)
from yh010 y
group by y.mandt, y.ktopl, y.yhkonto;
```

Your actual results and resulting query don't match the description, leaving me a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, I want that, and that is what I have in my `INNER JOIN`. What I want is to get the full table and an additional column with the distinct values grouped by those fields

Answer (score 0):

Antonio,

Could you please test following SELECT statement with CTE expression

```
with cte as (
select
    distinct mandt, ktopl, yhkonto, yhhykto
from TBL1
)
select 
    TBL1.*, (
    select count(cte.yhhykto) 
    from cte
    where
    TBL1.mandt = cte.mandt and
    TBL1.ktopl = cte.ktopl and
    TBL1.yhkonto = cte.yhkonto
    ) as cnt
from TBL1
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Eralper. Unfortunately it has the same `EXEC PLAN` in HANA as the one I posted. And it looses a bit of performance. So with a larger set of data I think it will not be the best approach